Personification of Esav in Western Civilisation - basis for Rabbi Mendel Kessin's teaching
Rabbi Mendel Kessin explains in this shiur (around 15 minutes in) that Christianity is the spiritual inheritor of Esav, and Western Civilisation is broken up into three parts, representing 3 parts of Esav:

Russia represents the arrogance of Esav
Europe represents the fraud of Esav
America represents the lust of pleasure seeking of Esav

He also explains that America has some of the evil of Esav, but also the good of Esav.
He says he explained this before. He has many shiurim so does someone know which shiur he explains it in, or even better - what sources he bases these very specific points on?

I believe it's his own perush, thought it's not hard to see what he's drawing on

Where does R. Kessin place Latin America?
